# Rationalisation of stabilising dispersion interactions in HgS via QM

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, hsab, dispersion-correction

It is well-known that mercury(II) sulfide, HgS, is extremely inert- for example, it has one of the lowest solubilities of nearly all known compounds in water(check Wikipedia). There are two well-known ways to rationalise this interness; one is HSAB theory, in this case that the LUMO of the mercury(II) cation is relatively low (soft acid) while the HOMO of the sulfide anion is relatively high (soft base), and the other is that the core 5d electrons of Hg(II) are relatively high in energy, sufficiently high enough to "dispersively interact" with the diffuse electrons of S(-II).

However, the conventional quantum chemical method CCSD(T), and to a lesser extent DFT, do not explain the latter in a satisfactory manner. All the former does is to include the excited states of HgS, and the crucial functional of the latter is not even known in closed form.

My question now follows- how does one explain the dispersion interaction of (say) two filled orbitals via excited-state-including, so-called "correlated" wavefunctions methods, and/or via the exact DFT functional?